# python function to calculate 5th and 95th confidence intervals of TLS regression slope.

Tags: python, linear-regression, statsmodels

I know the [statsmodels function](http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.regression.linear_model.OLS.html) for simple ordinary least squares (OLS) can [calculate confidence intervals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44302099/python-statsmodels-ols-confidence-interval) on the parameters. Is there a python function that can do the same but for Total Least Squares (TLS)?

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [2,3,4,5,2,4,5,4,2,2,1,8,9]

mean_a = numpy.mean(a)
std_a = numpy.std(a)

conf_int = scipy.stats.norm.interval(0.95, loc=mean_a, scale=std_a)

print(conf_int)
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Lack of explanation makes it difficult to understand why this would calculate the CI of the slope. Seems like you are just calculating the CI of the distribution of the data itself.